How to fix the issues after giving the command chroot?
Previously I got issues with both the lightdm and gdm3. Due to that I am still stuck in the gnome login screen and then to TTY. I am using a Kali linux 2024.2 ARM 32-bit OS.
After a rebooting the system I got other errors such as
You are in a emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, 

"systemctl reboot, or "exit" to continue bootup.

Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked.

See sulogin(8) man page for more details.

Press Enter to continue.

I gave the following to fix it which was wrong
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
sudo chroot /mnt
passwd root

It triggered the next errors and more worsening
sudo apt update
sudo: unable allocate pty: No such device

I tried a reboot
reboot
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bust: Host is down

I also checked as
ps -p 1 -o commm=
systemd

Has anyone else found the fix for such issues ? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Reinstall Kali. It is not meant as an OS for easy use or repair, but more for pen testing.
